# span is still showing for some reason in php if statement

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, if-statement

So I have two if statements for one of the fields of the form I'm working on. One is to check if the field(email) is empty or not, and the other one is to check if the email typed is in a right format. If a statement is false, it should show an error message with span tag. However, a span tag is still showing in the code even though the statement is true.

Here is the code.

```
<?php if( empty($data['email']) ): ?>
    <span class="error_list"><?php echo $error[5]; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( !preg_match( '/^[0-9a-zA-Z_.\/?-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$/', $data['email']) ): ?>
    <span class="error_list"><?php echo $error[6]; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm assuming there's something wrong with the way I put span tags in if statements, but I'm not sure.

I would appreciate any comments. Thank you.

**================================ EDIT =================================**

Please forgive me, apparently there was not enough information above.
I'm going to provide the following codes.

HTML part(email part only) There are two lines of span tags echoing $error[5] and $error[6] inside.

```
<div class="element_wrap">
    <label class="label"><span class="red_ast">※</span>メールアドレス<span class="contactfm_eng_title">E-MAIL</span></label>
    <?php if( !empty($error) ): ?>
         <?php if( empty($data['email']) ): ?>
             <span class="error_list"><?php echo $error[5]; ?></span>
         <?php endif; ?>
         <?php if( !preg_match( '/^[0-9a-zA-Z_.\/?-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$/', $data['email']) ): ?>
             <span class="error_list"><?php echo $error[6]; ?></span>
         <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <input placeholder="半角で入力してください" name="email" type="text" value="<?php if( !empty($clean['email']) ){ echo $clean['email']; } ?>">
</div>
```

Validation parts to put out $error[5] and $error[6]

```
<?php
function validation($data) {
    $error = array();
    if( empty($data['email']) ) {
        $error[5] = "「メールアドレス」は必ず入力してください。";
    }elseif( !preg_match( '/^[0-9a-zA-Z_.\/?-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$/', $data['email']) ) {
        $error[6] = "「メールアドレス」は正しい形式で入力してください。";
    }
   return $error;
}
?>
```

Sanitizing

```
if( !empty($_POST) ) {
    foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        $clean[$key] = htmlspecialchars( $value, ENT_QUOTES);
    } 
}
```

I'm also sharing the images to explain what's happening exactly.
There are two cases to explain, but the issue is the same.

> The first case

I put the email address in a wrong format on purpose(It's missing "@" and giving $error[6]) However, as you can see in the image1, there's also a line of span tags shown above the spans with $error[6].

**image1**

[image]

**image2**

[image]

I'm assuming it's from this line.

```
<span class="error_list"><?php echo $error[5]; ?></span>
```

It's empty inside the span tags so I know that it didn't give $error[5], which is supposed to be put out when nothing is typed in the field. Here, I don't understand how the line of span tags are there still when the input field is filled. The span tags should not be put out in html because of this part, am I right?

```
<?php if( empty($data['email']) ): ?>
```

> The second case

The second case is the opposite of the one I explained above. This time, I left the field empty to give $error[5]. The layout is how it should be, but the other span tags are there again.

**image3**

[image]

**image4**

[image]

The post ended up so long, and I know the situation is poorly explained, but any helps would be highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You should double-check your conditions. You can verify the value of each condition using var_dump(). One of them returns probably true.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code? For what input value do you get an unexpected result, and what is that result?

Comment: "a span tag is still showing" Which span tag is showing? Also, please show us your HTML form.

Comment: @Nick Please take a look at the codes I've provided.

Comment: @kmoser Thank you for the comment. Please take a look at the codes I've provided.

Comment: @Ryo You should really simplify your question by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which would include your HTML form. Without the HTML form, there's no way to tell what's going on for certain.

Comment: @kmoser Thank you for pointing out. Yes, I think you're right. Since this is a form created by PHP, the structure is a bit complex. I'll rethink my question and make a new post.